# generating function for pennies

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am done with three parts but having problem with these two parts. Can anybody assist

> - Write the generating function for the number of ways to use pennies, nickles, dimes, quarters and half-dollars to give $n$ cents change.
> - Explain how to use this function to find out how many ways are there to change $50$ cents; you do not have to provide the answer actually carry out the process.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724627/general-form-for-this-problem

Comment: What's the difficulty you encountered?

Comment: what will be the generating function for half dollars

Comment: will it be (1/1-x^50)

Comment: For those of us who don't use this coin system, it might be better to include the values of each type...

Comment: Hammy, I suggest you carefully read through the post that I linked. It's basically the same problem.